# selecting sql variable returning an empty array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to `SET` 3 variables in **MySQL** and get the sum of two of them.

The fist two variables, `@cFollow` and `@cComment`, *should* return an integer value each (the count of how many rows are returned); the third one is the sum of those two integers.

This is my **SQL**:

```
SET @cFollow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE unix > :unix AND following = :user);
SET @cComment = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_unix > :unix AND comment_track IN (SELECT upload_id FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist = :user));

SET @total = @cFollow + @cComment;

SELECT @total;
```

When I tested this on PHPMyAdmin, it returned the correct values and worked perfectly fine. However, when I tested it within **PHP**, it returned an empty array.

This is my **PHP**:

```
$holdPoint = (int)Input::get("hold_point");

$_SQL = "
SET @cFollow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE unix > :unix AND following = :user);
SET @cComment = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_unix > :unix AND comment_track IN (SELECT upload_id FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist = :user));

SET @total = @cFollow + @cComment;

SELECT @total;";
$_PARAMS = [":unix" => $holdPoint, ":user" => $user_id];

$check = DB::getInstance()->queryPro($_SQL, $_PARAMS);  
var_dump($check);
```

This is the result of that `var_dump`:

```
array(0){} // not very impressive...
           // should be something like int(1) instead
```

I've been searching around all night learning how to return a variable in **PHP** from a **MySQL** query, and this is as far as I've gotten.

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

Comment: Would you mind adding your php code, please

Comment: @Neobugu sure, but I'm using classes to query and validate, so it may seem a bit confusing.

Comment: Dont mind, we need your approach so we can test it and offer you a solution.

Comment: it's more confusing if you don't add the code..

Comment: Boom, updated @Neobugu

Comment: Check edit @RaymondNijland

Comment: I'm not sure which mysql API you're using, but unless you're using mysqli_multi_query (most likely not), you cannot pass more than 1 query/statement at a time. You'll have to pass each query separately.

Comment: @aynber I’m using PDO.

Comment: In that case, you'll definitely have to pass each query/SET statement separately.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not really meant as a answer but more as a comment. 
Also note that your queries

```
SET @cFollow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM followers WHERE unix > :unix AND following = :user);
SET @cComment = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comment_unix > :unix AND comment_track IN (SELECT upload_id FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist = :user));

SET @total = @cFollow + @cComment;

SELECT @total;
```

Can be most likely be rewritten as one query

```
SELECT 
 SUM(alias.c) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM followers WHERE unix > :unix AND following = :user
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM comments WHERE comment_unix > :unix AND comment_track IN (SELECT upload_id FROM uploads WHERE upload_artist = :user)
) AS alias
```

Comment: Ooh did not know this, will try this out too! :D

Comment: I'm assuming `alias` is similar, if not the same as, `dual`?

Comment: Then what is alias?

Comment: the `FROM (SELECT ...)` part needs to have a `alias` just like a column can have one i just called the subquery alias `alias` but you can call it everything you want.

Comment: Btw, this answer doesn't exactly help me in understanding **why** my code doesn't seem to want to work. Also, for some reason your answer always returns the number 6?

Comment: *"Btw, this answer doesn't exactly help me in understanding why my code doesn't seem to want to work. Also, for some reason your answer always returns the number 6? "* @GROVER. i or nobody else can explain why see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.